# How I update database after session gets destroyed?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-listeners

In my website I am creating  a session when a user opens the home page. Now if he adds some items into the cart , items will be saved in a db table with session id and item id as a column. Now if someone closes his browser then items with those session IDs should get deleted. If I use sessionDestroyed() method then how can I get the session ID of the session which get destroyed ? Because I have to have the session id to delete the items from the table. Can I import HttpServletRequest in listener class ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface provides the method

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent)
```

which gives you access to a [`HttpSessionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html) object with a method

```
public HttpSession getSession()
```

that

> Return the session that changed.

With the Session, you can then call [`getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId%28%29) and use the returned ID to remove rows from your database.